# Reload all dropdownlist after I clear one dropdown in c#

Tags: c#

So, here it is my problem
I have four dropdowns in the screen, and all four are loaded when the screen loads, also when I change the first combobox, all three load with the selectedindex method, no problems in that.

But when I manually clear the first combobox, the remaining three retain the same values as before and I am not able to reset them. Any suggestions ?

```
                private void comboBox_commodity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {

                        //filter stat type
                        if (!comboBox_commodity.Text.Equals(""))
                        {
                            statTypes = new List<string>();
                            foreach (string groupID in groupIds)
                            {
                                string sql = "select [ERSStatisticType_Attribute] from " + schemaName + "ERSStatisticType_LU " +
                                    "WHERE ERSStatisticType_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT[ERSCommodity_ERSStatisticType_ID] FROM  "
                                    + schemaName + "[ERSCommodityDataSeries]   WHERE [ERSCommodity_ERSGroup_ID] = " + groupID
                                    + " and ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID = " + getCommodityID(comboBox_commodity.Text) + " ) ";
                                DataTable dt = GetData(sql);
                                DataRow[] dr = dt.Select();
                                foreach (DataRow row in dr)
                                {
                                    statTypes.Add(row["ERSStatisticType_Attribute"].ToString());
                                }
                            }


                            comboBox_statType.DataSource = statTypes;
                            comboBox_statType.SelectedItem = null;

                            //filter unit


                            //filter source 
                            source = new List<string>();
                            foreach (string groupID in groupIds)
                            {
                                string sql = "select DISTINCT ERSSource_Desc from " + schemaName
                                + "ERSSource_LU where ERSSource_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT[ERSCommodity_ERSSource_ID] FROM  " + schemaName + "[ERSCommodityDataSeries]   WHERE [ERSCommodity_ERSGroup_ID] = " + groupID +
                                    " and ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID = " + getCommodityID(comboBox_commodity.Text) + " ) ORDER BY ERSSource_Desc";

                                DataTable dt = GetData(sql);
                                DataRow[] dr = dt.Select();
                                foreach (DataRow row in dr)
                                {
                                    source.Add(row["ERSSource_Desc"].ToString());
                                }
                            }


                            comboBox_source.DataSource = source;
                            comboBox_source.SelectedItem = null;

                            unit = new List<string>();
                            foreach (string groupID in groupIds)
                            {
                                string sql = "select distinct ERSUnit_Desc from " + schemaName
                                    + "ERSUnit_LU ulu" + "," + schemaName + "ERSCommodityDataSeries cds" + "," + schemaName + "ERSDataValues dv " +
                                    " where ulu.ERSUnit_ID=dv.ERSDataValues_ERSUnit_ID " +
                                    " and cds.ERSCommoditySubCommodity_ID= " + getCommodityID(comboBox_commodity.Text) +
                                    " and cds.ERSCommodity_ID=dv.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID " +
                                    " and [ERSCommodity_ERSGroup_ID] = " + groupID;


                                DataTable dt = GetData(sql);
                                DataRow[] dr = dt.Select();
                                foreach (DataRow row in dr)
                                {
                                    unit.Add(row["ERSUnit_Desc"].ToString());
                                }
                            }


                            comboBox1_unit.DataSource = unit;
                            comboBox1_unit.SelectedItem = null;

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            fillCommodityCombobox();
                            fillSourceCombobox();
                            fillUnitCombobox();
                            fillStatTypeCombobox();
                        }




                    }
```

If I manually clear the combobox, all other three values should be loaded with all the revelant values.

Comment: Which web framework are you using?  Your query is susceptible to injection, also remember after the method fires you need to rebind based on the data change to load the new content in the select.

Comment: @Greg sorry to ask, can a sample code be provided, something I can work on,

Comment: Sample code for?

Comment: for rebinding all combobox after I manually clear the first one

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm not 100% on your utilization here, but based off the initial issue I would use the Textupdate Event Handler like this:

```
    private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearCmboboxesOnFirstEmpty(comboBox_commodity.Text);
    }

    private void ClearCmboboxesOnFirstEmpty(string comboValue)
    {
        if(comboValue == "")
        {
            fillCommodityCombobox();
            fillSourceCombobox();
            fillUnitCombobox();
            fillStatTypeCombobox();
        }
    }
```